# best practice for calling a callback with parameters in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

i have a simple project with react js.in my project i have a span with an id. when onMouseEnter event occured on span id of span is displayed.and when onMouseLeave event occured id is removed.
i have two functions(showId and removeId).they are callbacks for onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events.showId accept one parameter.and i call this function in onMouseEnter event as follows
onMouseEnter(()=>showId(id)) but i think this is not optimal way.is it better way for doing this because every time that onMouseEnter event happened a new function created.

this is my app.js

```js
import './App.css';
import React, {useState} from "react";

function App() {

    const spanId = '1';

    const [id, setId] = useState(null);
    const showId = (id) => {
        setId(id);
    }
    const removeId = () => {
        setId(null);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <span id={spanId} onMouseEnter={() => {
                showId(spanId)
            }} onMouseLeave={removeId}>Hover me</span>

            {id ? <div>{id}</div> : null}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: An anonymous arrow function is the norm. If it's only the `id` you need you can access it from the implicitly passed `event`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `React.useCallback` to memoize callback with the `id` parameter.

```
const showId = useCallback(()=>{
  setId(spanId)
}, [setId, spanId]);
```

This callback is now [memoized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and does not accept parameters and will only ever get redefined if reference to `setId` or `spanId` change.

Use it like so:

```
<span id={spanId} onMouseEnter={showId} />
```

That said, this is such a simple function that it's probably better to simply redefine it on each render, since the `useCallback` is probably heavier in terms of CPU cycles than redefining your callback.

Comment: I'd also consider switching to changing only a flag here (show/hide), just in this particular case.

Comment: thanks . but if i had several ids and that ids came from a server in this case how can use this approach.for example i have dynamic number of li tag and id of this tags come from backend.

Comment: You can use this code for that 
const handleMouseChange = useCallback((spanId) => {
    setId(spanId)
  }, [setId]);